# Simple htaccess rewrite to show a different URL

Tags: apache

I want following url:

```
example.com/locations
```

to point to:

```
example.com/locations/?dest=los+angeles&lat=34.0522342&long=-118.2436849
```

but I don't want the user to see that long URL. i.e. user should only see `example.com/locations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your .htaccess file

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^locations$ locations/?dest=los+angeles&lat=34.0522342&long=-118.2436849
```